# How to extend data in one column using xlsxwritter python

Tags: python, django, xlsxwriter

How to extend data in one column seperated by commas in xlsxwriter.

```
for x in y:
   worksheet.merge_range("G"+str(row)+":"+"L"+str(row),x.multiple_values, centercell)
   row+=1
```

my data is dynamic for every loop i want to write values seperated by commas in particular column. for example

```
column A | column B

data     | 654654,649824,63928,624684
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved by using an empty string something like this and it worked for me

```
array =''
for x in y:
   array = str(x)+','+str(array)
   worksheet.merge_range("G"+str(row)+":"+"L"+str(row), array , centercell)
```

row+=1